# unable to verify a signed message in solidity

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, web3py

I am using this tutorial : https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-message

```
##  in web3py

sig = Web3.soliditySha3( [uint256, address], [tokens, contractaddress] ) ## used below also
output: HexBytes('0x3efb3cf4e41109f6f1f998401d02dbe894719a8806f45e79a5fab7d4799f00bb')
```

```
from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct
msg = sig.hex()
message = encode_defunct(text=msg)
signed_message = w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, private_key=private_key)
signed_message

SignedMessage(messageHash=HexBytes('0x4c0c7077f770069785167e8b7451d63fad1e858ef5251b239eb0781c314000d2'), r=5665764915496639843348851536709769469640799172147461427941649091688603148258, s=48121517563314450138554207713326165180739298862566159641495137088718857193470, v=27, signature=HexBytes('0x0c86b594baa5bb06a0f4054ffdf3896377cfb757d42dcaeacf0241d96a4d5fe26a63d0514338ec600c89ee808dc088e7b3aadc55b9f5d86685d3ff212e2e47fe1b'))
```

When I pass these params such as `signed_message.messageHash` and `signed_message.signature` to the recoversigner(mentioned below) function in the smart contract. It gives the correct address. But when I am passing arguments `tokens, contractaddress` (used above) to the solidity `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token,address(this)))` the message that is genarated is different from the `signed_message.messageHash` and in turn I get a different address as output from `ecrecover`.

I checked what is the output of `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(..))`. 
I found It is same as sig value

What I have done:

1. Make an ERC20 token.
2. setup the channel

My goal:

1. sign messages (with web3py)
2. validate the signed message with solidity.

Like this:

user will pass some arguments : like contract address and number of tokens along with the signed message. and I will validate it with

```
    function splitSignature(bytes memory sig)
        pure
        internal
        returns (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s)
    {
        require(sig.length == 65 , "invalid length");

        assembly {
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }
        if (v < 27) {
            v += 27;
        }

        require(v == 27 || v == 28 , "value of v ");
        return (v, r, s);
    }

    function recoverSigner(bytes32 message, bytes memory sig)
        internal 
        pure
        returns (address)
    {
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = splitSignature(sig);
        return ecrecover(message, v, r, s);
    }
```

```
bytes32 message = prefixed(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token,address(this))));
```

This is not working properly. I am not getting the correct address as output.

Please help..

Comment: Are you designing your own message-signing approach in a contract or trying to interact with an existing one? You mention getting different results, but it's not clear to me which one you want. If you are designing your own message-signing dapp, I highly recommend checking out the EIP-191 intended validator (version 0), or EIP-712 for typed signed messages.

Comment: I am not making a message signing dapp sir. What I am trying to do is make an ERC20 toek and build a micropayment channel with it. Now, the problem is coming like .. watever arguments the user passes with the signature. I can't retrive my address with it. Because `Web3.soliditySha3` and solidity's `keccak256` gives the same result. And while constructing a message in solidity I want to use arguments such as token and recipient address, contract address. But when `keccak256` is used.. to hash it.. the right asddress is not retrieved. Hope I am clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but an important clarification to make here is that Web3's `eth.sign` (and its underlying JSON-RPC call `eth_sign`) do not sign a simple hash. It adds a prefix string, with a length embedded.

See the [`eth_sign` docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sign):

> The sign method calculates an Ethereum specific signature with: `sign(keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + len(message) + message)))`.

By adding the prefix to the passed message, your client makes sure that you aren't using `eth_sign` to sign a transaction (presumably, by accident, or due to attack).

Calling `recoverHash(sig, ...)` is sort of nonsensical. Although the variable is called "`sig`", it is just a hash of some data -- it hasn't been signed by anything.

---

If you are designing a new message signing scheme, I *highly* recommend using some kind of standard. If you want the simplest possible option, you could use [EIP-191](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-191)'s "Version 0" message.

For that, you can use eth-account's [`encode_intended_validator()`](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/stable/eth_account.html#eth_account.messages.encode_intended_validator), which would look something like:

```
from eth_account.messages import encode_intended_validator
message = encode_intended_validator(YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDR, sig)
signed_message = w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, private_key=private_key)
```

Comment: As you mentioned `Although the variable is called "sig", it is just a hash of some data -- it hasn't been signed by anything` you are  correct sir.. but i also checked the output of `keccak256` in solidity. they exactly match..

Comment: `If you are designing a new message signing scheme` -- Sir, I just want to send micropayment messages ..and then latyer validate it.. with some arguments which the user will pass. such as number of tokens

Comment: `Calling recoverHash(sig, ...) is sort of nonsensical` -- i was looking for reason as to wwhy i can't retrieve the signer id in solidity.

Comment: `encode_intended_validator` is also not helping.. i cannot obtain the correct address.